How to move objects in a collection with interval using geometry node


Hello Good day, how can I move objects with interval instead of moving after the each object is finished. Thank you.

The phrase "move objects with interval instead of moving after the each object is finished" is not clear. What does "with interval" mean? Does the attached GIF show the desired, or undesired effect?

@TheLabCat Hello, with reference to the animation, the 2nd sphere moves only after the first sphere hit the bottom and so on, what I want to achieve  is  I want the 2nd sphere to follow the first sphere after a few frames or say while the first sphere is still on the middle distance from the bottom, the 2nd sphere will already start moving.

Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

You can use just math instead of selection.
Set an interval between each instance (as a number of frames), when the current frame is greater than this interval, things start moving.

File


Thank you Daniel Möller, this is what I want to achieve.

@Kaluy.Ph, if this answers your question, please mark it as answered so the community knows it.

Hi, may I know what math formula or equation you used to obtain this result? because I really want to understand how this is happening, I am thinking like this is just "y=mx + c", where "y" is the index value and "x" is scene time, I have been trying to create a formula but its not working every time. I hope you can help me, thank you.
